# Puppet not executing command. Getting stuck and giving timeout

Tags: linux, puppet, pm2

```
exec { "stop old application instance":
    cwd => "${install_dir}",
    path => ['/usr/bin','/bin','/usr/sbin','/sbin', '/bin/unlink', '/usr/local', '/usr/local/bin/'],
    onlyif => "test -e '${install_dir}/${app_package_dir}/processes.json'",
    group => 0,
    user => 'root',
    command => "pm2 delete /var/lib/application_folder/processes.json"
}
```

Puppet is getting stuck here and not able to execute the command. Not understanding the reason. Error log is given bellow

```
Error: Command exceeded timeout
Wrapped exception:
execution expired
Error: /Stage[main]/application::Install/Exec[stop old application instance]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed: Command exceeded timeout
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Running in `--debug` mode should give you more details about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

https://ask.puppet.com/question/1308/command-exceeded-timeout/

Puppet by default expects your command to finish running in 300 seconds or less.  Then it gives up waiting and assumes the command failed.

I know nothing about pm2 to help you figure out why your command is taking so long.  But if that's normal, then the link above suggests you add

`timeout     => 1800,`

to your puppet definition.

Comment: Thanks for replying but it is not a timeout problem. Puppet is not getting the pm2 command. I have tried with time out 0.

Comment: @MustafaMamun, from the log excerpt, it sure *looks* as if Puppet is trying to execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to manually find where the `pm2` command is coming from ( `$ which pm2` ) and then using the entire path of the command instead of using the `path` property. Something like this:

```
exec { "stop old application instance":
    cwd => "${install_dir}",
    onlyif => "test -e '${install_dir}/${app_package_dir}/processes.json'",
    user => 'root',
    command => "/usr/bin/pm2 delete /var/lib/application_folder/processes.json",
    logoutput => 'onfailure',
}
```

Notice the `logoutput` property to see the output of the command only in case something breaks. I don't think you need to specify the group

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put below in your puppet global script file :

```
Exec {
timeout => 0,
}
```